# Service worker - Can't specify width of browser in sw.js

Tags: service-worker

I want to be able to change width on my images depending on the size of the browser, so I am trying to specify the width of the browser with `document.body.clientWidth` within my sw.js. But I get the error saying that document is not defined.

Any other suggestions in how to get the size of the browser, or how I can wait until document is defined?

**sw.js**

```
var connection = "4g";
if (typeof navigator.connection != "undefined") {
    var connection = navigator.connection.effectiveType;
}
var isQualitySet = false;
var imageQuality = "";
var tabletUP = document.body.clientWidth < 500;
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if (/\.jpg$|.png$|.gif$|.webp$/.test(event.request.url)) {
        if (!isQualitySet) {
            switch (connection) {
              case '4g':
                imageQuality = 'q_auto:good';
                break;
              case '3g': 
                imageQuality = 'q_auto:eco';
                break;
              case'2g':
              case 'slow-2g':
                imageQuality = 'q_auto:low';
                break;
              default:
                'q_auto:best';
                break;
            }
            isQualitySet = true;
        }
        var fixWidth = "";
        if(!tabletUP) != -1) {
            fixWidth = ",w_170";
        }
        var fixedImg = "https://example.org/"+imageQuality+fixWidth+"/"+event.request.url;
        var finalImageURL = new URL(fixedImg);
        event.respondWith(
          fetch(finalImageURL.href, { headers: event.request.headers })
        );
    }
  }
);
```

**app.js**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
            console.log('Service Worker registered! Scope: '+registration.scope);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Service Worker registration failed: '+err);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because the service worker is running on it's own thread and not with the main thread of your website.

it's a bit like it would run server-side.

your images should get inside the service workers cache when they get loaded on your website. it's definitiv the wrong location for this check.